# How to create a relation with multiple tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

What I'm doing now, possibly mistaken:

```
users:
id,name

actions:
id, user_id

events:
id, action_id, description

posts
id, event_id, text
```

What I would like:

A User can create many actions.

An Action can have one Event

An Event can have many posts, but should be related to just one Event

The "trick" is I want that my Actions to have many posts, so I assume that creating the Event table was right.

What kind of relation should be set up assuming this?

Comment: Did you mean to say that `An Action can have many posts but should be related to just one Event`?

Comment: Exactly, but I will take it as: `An Action can have many posts but should be related to many Event` if it is "not possible"

Answer (score 0):

Since `An Action can have many posts but should be related to just one Event`, this is a simple join.

```
SELECT users.*, actions.*, events.*, posts.* FROM users 
LEFT JOIN actions ON users.id = actions.user_id 
LEFT JOIN events ON actions.id = events.action_id
LEFT JOIN posts ON events.id = posts.events_id
```

As mentioned in the comment above, there is not a need for the events table if an action is only ever going to have only 1 event AND the event is unique to that action - meaning the event won't be used in the future by another action.

---

Regarding you comment above that `An Action can have many posts but should be related to many Events`, this wouldn't change the join.

Comment: Another actions could become a reality. I may have a table named Action 1 and another Action 2. Both could have many posts and may be related to an Event (separated events)

Comment: I would suggest including a few rows of sample data with the expected query result. I would be happy to help further given that info. Based on your description, it is difficult for me to understand the true relationship between actions, events, & posts.

Comment: Lets switch the names to see if that makes it clear. `Tables: User (id), Events (id), Party(id, user_id),  Meeting (id, user_id), Comments (id, event_id)`

Comment: What im trying to say is that `Party or Meeting belongs to User. Party or Meeting has many Comments`.

Comment: Now that you are using `or` as in `Party or Meeting` belong to user... it is even more imperative that you provide sample data with expected outcome. It doesn't require a lot of data, but enough to show what you need. There is a simple example of providing data [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520049/mysql-extracting-information-from-table-with-select-join-count). However, please give the expected result.