# MySQL -- extracting information from table with select/join/count()

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a MySQL homework assignment, and one thing I am supposed to do is 
  "Display the department code along with the number of employees that are assigned to that department."

I've tried many different commands, including the command listed below, but I just can't seem to get the correct result based on the tables below.

Any ideas on how to get the requested sub-table? I've given the relevant tables below.

Thanks.

```
select code,count(distinct employee) 
from (department 
left outer join Assignment on department.code = assignment.department);
```

Department
Description|    Code|         Name|            Supervisor|      building|   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

“text”    |    OPR  |   Operating     |     77881234    |   BlockB|   
“text”    |     EMM    |    Emergency   |       54546677|       BlockA|   
“text”  |       MDR    |    Medical record|     99778525|       BlockA|

ASSIGNMENT
Employee|       Department  |   DateAssigned|       Role|   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
54546677 |      EMM         |     01/15/2011    |   Supervisor|   
54546677    |   EMM       |       02/25/2003|       Doctor|   
77881234    |   OPR     |         02/15/2010    |   Supervisor|   
77881234|       OPR   |           01/20/2000|       Doctor|   
77881234    |   EMM       |       02/20/1999    |   Doctor|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try using group by clause?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want. I have also added the Department Name too.
The GROUP BY clause will group the employees by department. 
This will allow you to count the number of employees.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT d.name FROM Department d WHERE d.Code = a.Department) AS DeptName,
a.Code as DeptCode,
COUNT(a.Employee) AS NumberOfEmployees
FROM assignment a
GROUP BY a.Department
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.code, COUNT(DISTINCT a.employee) AS employee_count
FROM Department AS d
LEFT JOIN Assignment AS a ON d.code = a.department
GROUP BY d.code
```

You need to use `GROUP BY` to get the count per department.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bdf13/2)